# Group by and summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to group according to 3 variables and create new variables with the summarise function.

My code:

Option 1

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

example2<-example%>%
  group_by(age_cohort,sex,city)%>%
  summarise(rich=sum(rich),
            middleclass=sum(middleclass),
            poor=sum(poor),
            population=count(id))
```

I don't understand the error:

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `population = count(id)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: age_cohort = 1, sex = 0, city = 1.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Option 2

```
example3<-example%>%
  group_by(age_cohort,sex,city)%>%
  summarise(rich=sum(rich),
            middleclass=sum(middleclass),
            poor=sum(poor),
            population=n(id))
```

The error:

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `population = n(id)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: age_cohort = 1, sex = 0, city = 1.
Caused by error in `n()`:
! unused argument (id)
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Furthermore, if I delete the 'population' variable I still having problems with my code.

New code

```
example<-example%>%
  group_by(age_cohort,sex,city)%>%
  summarise(rich=sum(rich),
            middleclass=sum(middleclass),
            poor=sum(poor))
```

The error:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"
```

The original data (example):

```
id  sex city    rich    middleclass poor    age_cohort
1   0   1   1   0   0   1
2   1   1   0   1   0   5
3   1   2   0   0   1   2
4   0   2   0   0   1   3
5   1   3   0   0   1   4
6   0   4   0   1   0   1
7   0   6   0   1   0   1
8   1   7   1   0   0   5
9   0   3   1   0   0   5
10  1   7   0   1       5
11  1   3   0   0   1   2
12  1   1   0   0   1   3
```

Comment: Your code block is working fine.  Have you created an object named `example`

Comment: The first one didn't work because `count` requires a data.frame.  You need `population = n())`.  Also, when you are updating the same object name `example` to the summarised one and then using that again can cause problems.  Please change the object name to a different one

Comment: What's the original `example`, before you re-assign it with the same name?

Comment: @akrun, I have tried to follow your instructions. Updated post

Comment: @AmaiaCarlin your second code works fine for me.  Please try on a fresh R session

Comment: @AndreaM the original example is at the end of the post. I have updated the post to prevent confusions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As akrun said, you need `population=n()`.

```
id <- 1:12
sex <- c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1)
city <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,6,7,3,7,3,1)
rich <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
middleclass <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0)
poor <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,NA,1,1)
age_cohort <- c(1,5,2,3,4,1,1,5,5,5,2,3)
example <- data.frame(id,sex,city,rich,middleclass,poor,age_cohort)

example3 <- example%>%
  group_by(age_cohort,sex,city)%>%
  summarise(rich=sum(rich),
            middleclass=sum(middleclass),
            poor=sum(poor),
            population=n())
```

Output

```
> example
   id sex city rich middleclass poor age_cohort
1   1   0    1    1           0    0          1
2   2   1    1    0           1    0          5
3   3   1    2    0           0    1          2
4   4   0    2    0           0    1          3
5   5   1    3    0           0    1          4
6   6   0    4    0           1    0          1
7   7   0    6    0           1    0          1
8   8   1    7    1           0    0          5
9   9   0    3    1           0    0          5
10 10   1    7    0           1   NA          5
11 11   1    3    0           0    1          2
12 12   1    1    0           0    1          3
> example3
# A tibble: 11 x 7
# Groups:   age_cohort, sex [7]
   age_cohort   sex  city  rich middleclass  poor population
        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
 1          1     0     1     1           0     0          1
 2          1     0     4     0           1     0          1
 3          1     0     6     0           1     0          1
 4          2     1     2     0           0     1          1
 5          2     1     3     0           0     1          1
 6          3     0     2     0           0     1          1
 7          3     1     1     0           0     1          1
 8          4     1     3     0           0     1          1
 9          5     0     3     1           0     0          1
10          5     1     1     0           1     0          1
11          5     1     7     1           1    NA          2
```

**Why you got errors**

As others have pointed out in the comments.

First error was due to `count` working on dataframes and variable names; it cannot be used as a summary function. For example, `count(example, sex)`. You gave `count` a numeric vector (`an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')`), which it couldn't take as argument (`no applicable method for 'count' applied to...`).

Second error was due to `n()` only returning information about the last grouping variable (see `?context`). This time, you gave it an argument while it doesn't take any since the last grouping variable is specified by `group_by`, so it returned `unused argument`.

The last error was due to you not creating an object `example` in the environment before executing `group_by`. Indeed, `example` is the name of a function in `utils` (see `?example`). So if you don't create an object with that name, R thinks you're referring to the function named `example`. Then you try to `group` it, which R can't because it only works on dataframes. You gave it an argument of class function (`an object of class "function"`) when it expects a dataframe.